# Jpa repository order by issue with native query

Tags: jpa

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Customer order by ?1 DESC", nativeQuery = true) 
List getSortPage(String perameter);
```

its not taking order by column dynamically , and returning the same result

Comment: please elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve

Answer (score -1):

`JPA` Query [doesn't support](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_orderby) `ORDER BY` usage by parameter. Only `WHERE` and `HAVING`.

1. Create separate `Query` for each ordered field
2. Create Query using [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html)